# Delphi GMap Direction Markers Substitution

Tags: delphi, google-maps, google-maps-markers, map-directions, gmlib

I have one direction between 2 predefined markers I double click (origin/destination).

When I change the position of one of the previously dblclicked markers, I want to change also the direction (origin or destination). (just like the direction markers do).

There is a way to substitute the direction markers with the ones already existing on the map ?

Note: `DirectionsRender.SuppressMarkers := true`;

Comment: No, you can not make that substitution. You can do this: when you dblclick into the second marker (to get direction), Marker.Visible property to false into the two originals markers. Thus you have only the markers of direction and you can drag it without any problem.

Comment: Thank one more time cadetill! I understand your solution.             The problem is that I can not find a way to particularize the directions markers (color, name, ...). MarkerOptions are limited: Clickable, Dragable, flat, Icon.                                                                        At this point the polylines seem to be solution.